# Git - adding changes from master to left-behind branch

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I have a branch that's way behind master. I want to pull the changes from master and integrate them into my branch, then push that updated local branch to the remote branch.

While on my feature branch, I used:

```
git merge origin/master branch1
```

This pulled some files, but nowhere near all of them - there's a 800-lines file on master that's only 200 after using this.

```
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
 src/assets/js/amcharts.js            | 69 +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 src/assets/js/line-chart.js          |  4 +-
 templates/partials/navs/main-nav.tpl |  3 +-
 templates/file.tpl       |  5 ---
 templates/settings/data.tpl          | 84 ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 www/settings/data.php                |  6 +++
 6 files changed, 164 insertions(+), 7 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 src/assets/js/amcharts.js
 create mode 100644 templates/settings/data.tpl
 create mode 100644 www/settings/data.php
```

What am I doing wrong? is there something else I should be doing?

Comment: no need to give sitting branch name only `git merge origin/master`  will do then `git push origin branch1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply checkout `branch1`. Pull `origin/master`. Then push to remote.

```
$ git checkout branch1
$ git pull origin master     # pull = fetch + merge
$ git push origin branch1    # update remote/branch1
```

**Overwrite a file with origin/master:**

> "... nowhere near all of them - there's a 800-lines file on master that's only 200 after using this.

You should *overwrite the file with origin/master*.

```
$ git checkout origin/master <file-name>
```

Comment: I don't want to merge my branch into master - I just want to add the changes from master onto my remote branch. It looks like this pushes my branch+master into master, correct?

Comment: It did pull more changes, but the file I use for reference is still only 200 lines long :(

Comment: Maybe you deleted some lines in your branch1's before commit. You can `reset a file with origin/master` by command `git checkout origin/master <file-name>`.

Comment: That's exactly what had happened. I had tried to do a rebase and it worked partially. That specific file got overwritten. Thanks!